# Is Phillip J. Fry based on Marty McFly?

Tags: futurama, back-to-the-future

Is the character of Phillip J. Fry based on Michael J. Fox's character, Marty McFly, from *Back to the Future*? There seems to be a lot of similarities between their three names and also their clothing and hair colour.

Comment: Maybe Phillip J. Fry is based on Phillip K. Dick?

Answer (score 4):

According to commentary from "Space Pilot 3000" Fry's outfit is based on James Dean's outfit from "Rebel without a Cause."
As far as hi personality, it was based on making a character that could appeal to the young male demographic and also encompass Groening love of the slow thinker archetype.
The J in Fry's name is a reference to the J in the names of Bullwinkle and Rocky.  It was joked in one audio commentary that the J stands for Jay.

Comment: Just like Homer Jay Simpson? Ha-Ha

Comment: Huh, I always though the J stands for "Jensie", which would be the German spelling of Yancy...